# How to print the json data using foreach loop in laravel-5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

The Controller code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

use DarthSoup\Whmcs\Facades\Whmcs;
use DarthSoup\Whmcs\WhmcsServiceProvider;

class GetProductController extends Controller
{
public function show(){
    $products = Whmcs::GetProducts([
        'pid'=>'pid',
        'name' =>'name',
        'price' =>'price',
        'description' =>'description'


    ]);

    return view('main.SME_Hosting',['products'=>$products]);


    }
}
```

And in Views I have written code using foreach as follows:

```
         @foreach ($products as $product)
               <td> {{$product->'pid'}}</td>
               <td> {{$product->'name'}}</td>
               <td> {{$product->'price'}}</td>
               <td> {{$product->'description'}}</td>

 @endforeach
```

My Json data is given below:
  I have attached the screenshot of JSON data and suggest a way to print all these datas using foreach loop.

Comment: And the problem or question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
     <pre>{{ $product | json }}</pre>
@endforeach
```

It will print all product data in json.

Answer (score 1):

You can have json form of your passed data using **@json** directive

```
var products = @json($products);
```